# Grease pencil stroke disappearing with rotation

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I am brand new to grease pencils and want to create some 2d stuff.
I want to create window with outlines but the outlines disappear with rotation.

[image]

[image]

I use blender 3.6, I tried changing clipping but it doesnt help.